# CSS: center textarea inside <td> for 100% table

Tags: html, css

**Currently**

I have a 100% width table that contains 2 columns within which there is a textarea where users can input text.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {}

.text-area {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <textarea class="text-area">This is a short piece of text.
            </textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <textarea class="text-area">This is a long piece of text, which ultimately should be displayed as a minimum with a width of 250 px
            </textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

```
https://jsfiddle.net/qvr2b8pu/3/
```

**Problem**

I want the text area to dynamically adjust to the screen width, and keep margins to the surrounding cell constant e.g. 10px <-- as per this example.

Goal:

[image]

I would like to keep the structure of the table and divs the same if this is possible to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `display:flex` for your `container` and then use the margin for `textarea`. I hope this solution will be helpful for you.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th,
td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.text-area {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="container">
                    <textarea class="text-area">This is a short piece of text.
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="container">
                    <textarea class="text-area">This is a long piece of text, which ultimately should be displayed as a minimum with a width of 250 px
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Crazy. The 'display: flex' was the key missing detail. Thank you very much.

Comment: it is not as per standards to use inside a table !

Comment: @AmarjitSingh Every problem have multiple solution. Consider this is one of way.

Comment: yes, but flex doesn't work with ie and other browsers, you have to use -ms-, -moz-, etc. I respect your answer but this website is to find out best possible solution. hope you get my point !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything complicated here. You've simply run into the classic box model issue, where the total width includes the left and right padding and borders as well as the specified width. The `box-sizing` property can be used to switch to the alternate box model where the `width` property is the total width.

```
textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This also works as the above answer. I am not sure yet which is the best solution for my needs / best practices.

Comment: One of the problems with this solution is that the container stretches a bit below the the textarea. See https://jsfiddle.net/982xpu64/3/. Any ideas on how to fix that? I'm not even sure of what causes this. Note: "display: flex" doesn't have this issue i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788427/1730260 solution

Comment: Oh, that space it there because a <textarea> is an inline element and has `vertical-align: baseline` by default. That causes a space for text descenders (like the bottom of the lowercase "g") to be made below it in the line-box. To fix that set the `vertical-align` property to `middle` or `top`.

Comment: Thank you. I actually combined your solution ' box-sizing: border-box' with 'display: flex' as it gave me the desired result I was after. Neither 1 solution was sufficient. This has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `box-sizing:border-box` to textarea as by default it is not border-box which make it go through div/td. Thanks !

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {}

.text-area {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <textarea class="text-area">This is a short piece of text.
            </textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <textarea class="text-area">This is a long piece of text, which ultimately should be displayed as a minimum with a width of 250 px
            </textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```