# CSS: adjust parent table column column width to contain child div, with additional columns using auto-width

Tags: html, css

**Currently**

I have a 100% width table that contains 3 columns within which there is a textarea where users can input text.

My goal is to have the following column width behaviors:

1. Column 1 = minimum width of 600px
2. Column 2 = auto width with respect to other columns
3. Column 3 = auto width with respect to other columns

Bonus goal: If screen width is small enough that 1 or more columns cannot full display, add a horizontal scroll.

Code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  
}

.text-area {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.fixed-min {
  min-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>Column 1 - has min width</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
          <div class="container fixed-min">
            <textarea class="text-area">Respect the minimum column width for this column.
            </textarea> 
          </div>
        </td>
    <td>
          <div class="container">
            <textarea class="text-area">This column width should revert to default for the table.
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
    <td>
          <div class="container">
            <textarea class="text-area">This column width should also revert to the default for the table.
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjLxuvfz/1/

**Problem**

Minimum width of 600px for column 1 is working, but the (1) class "container" and (2)  widths are not adjusting.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Expected behaviors:

1. When window size is 600px, Column 1 width = 600px, and Columns 2 and Columns 3 are at minimum auto-size. Optional: with horizontal scroll bar.
2. When window size is large e.g. 1000px+, Columns 1 to 3 are auto-sized, with Column 1 width > 600px.

**Note:**

1. I would like to keep the structure of the table and divs the same if this is possible to achieve the desired result.
2. This is building on my last query: [CSS: center textarea inside <td> for 100% table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788224/css-center-textarea-inside-td-for-100-table/55788733#55788733)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done changes according to requirement, To achieve thisremove `table-layout:fixed` and add a outer `div` to `table` to make it work in responsive/mobile mode. Please check hope this will solve your issue. Also i suggest to make th in thead as per standards.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

th, td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  
}

.text-area {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.fixed-min {
  min-width: 600px;
}
.res-table{
  max-width:100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div class="res-table">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th width="600px">Column 1 - has min width</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
          <div class="container fixed-min">
            <textarea class="text-area">Respect the minimum column width for this column.
            </textarea> 
          </div>
        </td>
    <td>
          <div class="container">
            <textarea class="text-area">This column width should revert to default for the table.
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
    <td>
          <div class="container">
            <textarea class="text-area">This column width should also revert to the default for the table.
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```